# How do I set all the checkboxes true?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a button that, when clicked, should make all the checkboxes true. But as a result, I get nothing. How were false and remained. There are no errors.

What did I do wrong?

**component.html:**

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="checked()">Set All</button>

<form [formGroup]="form">
    <mat-nav-list *ngFor="let notification of nvm.notifications; let i = index" formArrayName="data">
        <div formGroupName="{{ i }}" fxLayout="row">
            <mat-checkbox formControlName="is_read"></mat-checkbox>
        </div>
    </mat-nav-list>
</form>
```

**component.ts:**

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.nvm$ = this.store$.pipe(select(selectNotificationsViewModel));
    this.initializeForm();
    this.load();
  }

  public get data() {
    return this.form.get('data') as FormArray;
  }

  initializeForm(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      data: this.fb.array([]),
    });
  }


  checked(): void {
    this.nvm$.subscribe((e) => {
      e.notifications.forEach((notification) => {
        this.data.push(
          this.fb.group({
            is_read: this.fb.control({
              value: true,
            }),
            notification_id: this.fb.control(notification.notification_id),
          })
        );
      })
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

the number of your `checkbox` must be dependent to your `form.data` not the other way around, thus, in your

**component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <mat-nav-list formArrayName="data">
        <div *ngFor="let singledata of data.controls" fxLayout="row">
            <div [formGroup]="singledata">
               <mat-checkbox formControlName="is_read"></mat-checkbox>
            </div>
        </div>
    </mat-nav-list>
</form>
```

also, push already some formcontrols in your `ngOnInit()` with regards to your notification length with default `false` value in your

**component.ts**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.nvm$ = this.store$.pipe(select(selectNotificationsViewModel));
  this.nvm$.subscribe((e) => {
    e.notifications.forEach((notification) => {
      this.data.push(
        this.fb.group({
          is_read: [false]
          notification_id: [""]
        })
      );
    });
  });
}
```

then you can loop each controls in data and update using `patchValue` in your `checked()` function